# How to prove that one set of vectors forms the basis for another set of vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

**Question:** How do I prove that one given set of vectors forms the basis of another given set of vectors?

I know that if we could prove that both sets are identical to each other, then the first set would obviously span the second set. But are there any other simpler ways of proving that one set forms the basis of another set without having to go through every vector and see if they are present in both sets?

**Question Two:** If we combine the vectors in each set into a matrix and reduce the matrices to reduced row echelon form, could we simply say that one set spans the other if their row reduced echelon form are the same?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not quite understood the difference between a vector space and its basis. You van certainly not prove that a set is a basis for another set by showing that they are the same. With the exception of the trivial vector space, no vector space equals its own basis. A basis for a vectorset $V$ is a subset $\mathcal{B}$ of $V$ such that $\mathcal{B}$ is linearly independent in $V$ and spans $V$. So to prove that a set forms a basis you need to check (1) linear independence and (2) span.

If you want to check if two bases are bases for the same vector space, which might be what you are really asking, you need to compare their spans. If they span they same set, the form bases for the same set.

As to your second question, you may check whether a set of vectors $v_1, \ldots v_n$ form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ by considering the reduced row echelon form (rref) of the matrix with these vectors as column, i. e.

$$B = [ v_1 \quad v_2 \quad \cdots \quad v_n].$$

They form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ if and only if the rref of $B$ is the identity matrix. If the vector space in question is not the entire $\mathbb{R}^n$, you need to check if the column spaces of the two matrices you compare are the same.